# html lang code for Flemish language?

Tags: html, internationalization, tags

Anybody confirming the information provided by this [website](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/bllanguagecodes.htm)?:

> Dutch; Flemish    nl

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML language codes are defined in HTML 4.01 with a reference to RFC 1766. This is really outdated, since RFC 1766 was obsoleted in 2001 by RFC 3066, which was obsoleted in 2006 by RFC 4646, which was obsoleted in 2009 by [RFC 5656](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5646), which has got the BCP (Best Current Practice) status.

By reference to ISO 639 standards, and by a special rule that gives priority to two-letter basic language code (“primary subtag”) when it exists, RFC 5656 specifies `nl` for use for the Dutch language.

Whether Flemish is just a different name for Dutch, or a special form (variant) of Dutch, or a separate language, is subject to debate. But no “primary subtag” has been defined for it, and no registered variant subtag either. So you can use `nl` as such, or with a country subtag: `nl-BE`.

In practice, software that deals with HTML documents mostly ignores language codes (`lang` attributes). There are some exceptions, but in them, it is usually the major language code only that matters anyway – some programs make recognize a few variants like `en-US` and `en-GB`, though. Thus, a country subtag like `BE` would most probably have no effect (except that some old software might fail to recognize `nl-BE` at all, even if it recognizes simple language codes like `nl`).